# A play with sequence

Tags: knowledge, sequence

What should be the next two alphabets in a given sequence?

```
                 GE,RU,CH,GR,?
```

Comment: Doe this need that secial tag? Yu know, the one that' hidden in this commen. ight?

Comment: @Mithrandir: I think trivia is just fine.

Comment: Actually,I was not sure about it.....

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's

> **UN** for the United States. It's the first two letters of the countries with the most gold medals at the 2016 Olympics from fifth most to most (Germany, Russia, China, Great Britain, United States).